# INSERT GETDATE() but it insert value of 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, getdate

I am currently doing a code of inserting data into the database. Everything was fine except the date was not insert as what was I expect. 
I want to insert the current date so I used `GETDATE()` function to insert into the departDate column but the database show the result of `0000-00-00` instead of the current date. 
Here's how I insert my data.

```
INSERT INTO `route_master` (`route_id`, `busNo`, `noOfSeat`, `origin`, 
`destination`, `departDate`, `departTime`, `arrivalTime`, `price`) VALUES 
('47', 'BUA1245', '40', 'KOTA KINABALU INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT', '1 BORNEO', 
'GETDATE() ', '06:00', '06:55', '15.00')
```

I tried to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as well but it still show me the same result.
Anyone can help me to solve this?

Comment: Remove the quotes... `'1 BORNEO', GETDATE(), ...`

Comment: @Chuah Phang Hoong I updated my answer after your update, I think NOW() is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [NOW()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) instead of GETDATE(), and also remove the ' around GETDATE(), GETDATE() is a function in MySql. With the quotes is being interpreted as a string.

```
INSERT INTO `route_master` (`route_id`, `busNo`, `noOfSeat`, `origin`, 
`destination`, `departDate`, `departTime`, `arrivalTime`, `price`) 
VALUES 
('47', 'BUA1245', '40', 'KOTA KINABALU INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT', '1 
BORNEO', NOW(), '06:00', '06:55', '15.00')
```

If you are unsure what function to use, check this query to see which one gives you the values you want.

```
SELECT NOW(),CURDATE(),CURTIME();
```

The output of this is something like this:

> NOW()       -          CURDATE()   - CURTIME()
>
> 2017-05-11 11:00:00 - 2017-05-11 - 11:00:00

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly after i changed the GETDATE() to either NOW() or CURDATE() and removed the ' around the function.